# Sending data through the iphone headphone jack

Tags: swift, arduino, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I am working on an iPhone in Swift that will detect the button press from the arduino through the headphone jack.

I'll have a button installed on the arduino that will change the pins and the frequency.

I wasn't sure what framework should i use in the iOS - Should i use

- AVCaptureAudioDataOutput
- AVAudioRecorder

or something else?

Its just detecting the button press.

Thanks

Comment: AVAudioRecorder should work. There are some examples around.

Comment: @johnelemans trying to figure out which delegate method will provide me change in the frequency

Comment: look at this example; https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio

Comment: That's in the objective-C, i am doing SWIFT. I guess i can do bridge-header but would be more happy to find a tutorial in the SWIFT

Comment: translate the bits you need!

Comment: do you have or know any sample code? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used

```
  let averagePower = audioRecorder.averagePowerForChannel(0)
```

for getting the power.

On the hardware side used arduino UNO and generating the tone.